# How Get JSON value and re-use it in many function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, function

Now it work... but how i can write the right call for the json?

i tried with this direct link but doesn't work, maybe i've to edit the "data" parameters? I don't know because i read that is on optional parameter right? any help?

And ho w i can set the continuous refres of the json values that i want to pick to make them always updated (every 60s).

thanks!!

```
function itemManager(){
    var _me        = null;
    var _goldAsk   = 0;
    var _silverAsk = 0;
    var _eurusdAsk = 0;

    var construct = function(){
        //init here
        _me = $(this);
        _bindHandlers();
        _updateItem(125);
    }

    var _bindHandlers = function(){

        _me.on('stockupdated', function(){
            $('#gcost').text(_goldAsk + ' ' + _silverAsk + ' ' + _eurusdAsk);
        });

        $('#calculate').on('click', function(){
            alert("item gold ask(" + _goldAsk + ") vs silver ask(" + _silverAsk + ")");
        });

        $('#updateitem').on('click', function(){
            _updateItem(250);
        });

        $('#btnGetTotals').on('click', function(){
            var grammsOfGold   = $('#goldGramms').val().length   ? parseInt($('#goldGramms').val())   : 0;
            var grammsOfSilver = $('#silverGramms').val().length ? parseInt($('#silverGramms').val()) : 0;
            var carati = document.getElementById("carati").selectedIndex;

            alert('Total for gold: ' + (((( _goldAsk / 31.1034768 ) / _eurusdAsk) * (document.getElementsByTagName("option")[carati].value)) * grammsOfGold ).toFixed(2) + ' total for silver: ' + (grammsOfSilver * _silverAsk) + 'Carati selezionati: ' + (document.getElementsByTagName("option")[carati].value))
        });        

        $('#btnGetInfo').on('click', function(){
            alert('Gold ask: ' + ((_goldAsk / 31.1034768) / _eurusdAsk).toFixed(3) + ' silver ask: ' + ((_silverAsk / 31.1034768) / _eurusdAsk).toFixed(3)); 
        });
    }

    var _getMonth = function(){
        return parseInt($('#month').val());
    }

    var _updateItem = function(cost){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://quotes.instaforex.com/get_quotes.php?m=json&q=gold,silver,eurusd',

            data: {
                json: '{' +
                    '"GOLD":{"symbol":"GOLD","lasttime":1379116798,"digits":2,"change":"-0.09","bid":"1325.91","ask":"1326.51"},' +
                    '"SILVER":{"symbol":"SILVER","lasttime":1379116779,"digits":3,"change":"-0.010","bid":"22.170","ask":"22.210"},' +
                    '"EURUSD":{"symbol":"EURUSD","lasttime":1379116796,"digits":4,"change":"-0.0001","bid":"1.3296","ask":"1.3299"}' +
                '}',
                delay: 2
            },

            success: function(data){                
                _goldAsk   = parseFloat(data.GOLD.ask);
                _silverAsk = parseFloat(data.SILVER.ask);
                _eurusdAsk = parseFloat(data.EURUSD.ask);
                _me.trigger('stockupdated');
            }
        })
    }

    construct();
}

window.onload = function(){
    var item = new itemManager();
}
```

Comment: could be cross domain restriction http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy (you can try to request instaforex on server and pass result to client), for updating every 60 secs, use setInterval http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/vp9V6/

HTML

```
<div>Gold cost: <span id="gcost"></span></div>
months: <input type="text" id="month" />
<input type="button" id="calculate" value="GET TAXES" />
<input type="button" id="updateitem" value="UPDATE ITEM" />
```

Javascript

```
function itemManager(){
    var _me     = null;
    var _item   = {};

    var construct = function(){
        //init here
        _me = $(this);
        _bindHandlers();
        _updateItem(125);
    }

    var _bindHandlers = function(){

        _me.on('stockupdated', function(){
            $('#gcost').text(_item.cost);
        });

        $('#calculate').on('click', function(){
            alert("item cost(" + _item.cost + ") * month(" + _getMonth() + ") = " + (_item.cost * _getMonth()));
        });

        $('#updateitem').on('click', function(){
            _updateItem(250);
        });
    }

    var _getMonth = function(){
        return parseInt($('#month').val());
    }

    var _updateItem = function(cost){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/echo/json/',
            data: {
                json: '{"cost":"' + cost + '","currency":"USD"}',
                delay: 2
            },
            success: function(data){                
                _item.cost     = parseInt(data.cost);
                _item.currency = data.currency;
                _me.trigger('stockupdated');
            }
        })
    }

    construct();
}

window.onload = function(){
    var item = new itemManager();
}
```

Comment: i'll try... but i've to change url: '/echo/json/', with my link to the json.php file that search the url of instaforex.com or i've to put the url of instafore.com right there?

Comment: change to direct url, /echo/json/ is jsfiddle emulation of ajax call

Comment: EHI DART! pretty cool man, i costomize the code that you posted and now it works... on JSFIDDLE!
What i have to change to make the ajax json call to instaforex.com?
i tried with the code that i update into the question...
THANKS MATE!!!

Answer (score 0):

Set your variables in a scope that other functions can reference.

```
window.goldAsk = true;
window.silverAsk = { some: 'value' };
```

That will make them global.  If you are going to do this I would make an object to keep everything to do with this particular script like:

```
window.myProgram = {};
```

And then later you can simply:

```
myProgram.goldAsk = true;
```

Comment: could you make an example with my code to make me understand please?

Answer (score 0):

It's all about scope. Declare the variables outside (for example, in top of your page). Then assign the values without the **var** declaration:

```
// Make them global
var goldAsk, silverAsk, eurusdAsk;

$(document).ready(function(){

// segnalato dove andare a cercare ora definisco gli oggetti    
$.getJSON('json.php', function(json) {
 var gold = json.GOLD;
 var silver = json.SILVER;
 var eurusd = json.EURUSD;

  goldAsk = ((gold.ask / 31.1034768) / eurusdAsk).toFixed(3);
  silverAsk = ((silver.ask / 31.1034768) / eurusdAsk).toFixed(3);

  // operazioni di conversione
  eurusdAsk = eurusd.ask;

 // pubblico in DIV tramite funzione .text
  $(".container-quote").text('ORO: ' + goldAsk  + '   ' + 'ARGENTO: ' + silverAsk + '     *Quotazioni €/g in tempo reale aggiornamento ogni 3s. Quotazioni da www.instaforex.com    ' + '      ' + '        Quotazioni del cambio $/€ aggiornate in tempo reale dallo stesso database');

$('.grammibox input').keyup(multiply);
$('span.caratiselect select').change(multiply);
 });

function multiply() {
    var grammi = parseFloat($('.grammibox input').val());

    var carati = $('span.caratiselect select').val().substr(1);

    $('#totale').text('La tua valutazione: ' + ((goldAsk * carati) * grammi).toFixed(2));
}
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you are setting the value from inside of an AJAX call that takes some time to load. This means the value is not yet set to the variables. Move the AJAX call inside of $(document).ready(). Also, assign the event handlers from inside of the AJAX call.

Comment: ahahaha! i know...:)

i copied your code into the document but it doesn't work... i've wait but nothing... it say "NaN" any ideas? sorry but i'm really newbie :)

Comment: It's because eurusdAsk doesn't have a value (used when calculating goldAsk and silverAsk).